# How to match trait bounds in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to match the trait bounds for generic types:

```
macro_rules! test {
    (
        where $(
            $bounded_type:ident: $( $bound:tt )++,
        )+
    ) => {
        // Dummy expansion for test:
        struct Foo<T, U>
        where $(
            $bounded_type : $( $bound )++,
        )+
        {
            t: T,
            u: U
        }
    }
}

test! {
    where
        T: PartialEq + Clone,
        U: PartialEq,
}

fn main() {}
```

Unfortunately, if I understand well, the only way to match a trait is a `tt` fragment, but this fragment can match almost anything, so whatever I do, I get an error:

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('bound') or 1 other option.
```

How can I match this piece of code?

Note that I do not *need* something very elegant (I do not need it for plublic users) but of course, the more elegant, the better.

Comment: I had a lot of problems both matching and emitting type bounds. It was a while ago, but I think I ended up just doing something else instead...

Comment: @PeterHall The Rust team should do something about that. IMO, the macro system should permit to easily match and emit the language syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to read the [source code for the `parse-generics-shim` crate](https://github.com/DanielKeep/rust-parse-generics/tree/master/parse-generics-shim); it's a bit old, but should hopefully still work.  This is *way* too convoluted to explain in a Stack Overflow question, since it would basically involve copy+pasting the source of that crate into the answer.

The easier approach is to just *not* parse actual Rust syntax, and use something the macro parser *can* handle, like wrapping the constraints in a group (like `{ ... }`).

Comment: `parse_where_shim!` calls `parse_where!` in this file https://github.com/DanielKeep/rust-parse-generics/blob/master/parse-generics-shim/src/parse_where_shim.rs, but I cannot find the definition of the latter.

Comment: @Boiethios You'll note that the next macro is *also* called `parse_where_shim!` and has the exact inverse conditional compilation condition.  `parse_where!` was a proposed addition to the compiler that was rejected; hence the alternate implementation that doesn't use it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to match by splitting the first bound from the rest.

```
macro_rules! test {
    (
        where $(
            $bounded_type:ident: $bound:tt $(+ $others:tt )*,
        )+
    ) => {
        // Dummy expansion for test:
        struct Foo<T, U>
        where $(
            $bounded_type : $bound $(+ $others)*,
        )+

        {
            t: T,
            u: U
        }
    }
}
```

However, this isn't going to work if the traits have parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have generic trait bounds :( But your idea is good !

Comment: I initially expected `tt` to match things like  `Into<u32>` here actually.  I think you really want to use `ty`, but there are too many restrictions about what can follow it - e.g. `+` cannot.

Comment: I tried with `ty` with coma separator and semicolon termination, but when I try to expand the macro, I'm getting this error: `expected `where`, or `{` after struct name`

Answer (score 1):

Since around 2016 with the closing of [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38279), you could use the `path` macro type to match `TypePath`s.

For example, from my own code:

```rust
($name:ident<$($l:lifetime, )*$($x:ident : $xt:path),+>($s:ident$(, $a:ident: $t:ty)*) -> $ret:ty  => $body:block) => {
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by this answer and [the documentation on `TypePath`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-types).  Going by the name, I would expect a `TypePath` to be the `foo::bar` in `foo::bar::MyType`. `$type:ty` will already match types in general, including the `foo::bar` part, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Also does this handle bounds with more than one constraint, e.g. `T: Clone + Eq`?